# greyed-out folders on OSX with wrong date

Tags: macos, finder

Had a backup fail due to power hit. Was running on OSX10.9 to a Win server (XenData LTO). Widows can see folder fine, though the date is 1984. Mac sees folder greyed-out, "get info" says folder created also in 1984. Microsoft TechNet forum sees same issue (Finder issue), but offers no solution. Is the folder hidden? how do I unhide it so I can delete it, so I can re-run this backup?

Answer (score 0):

If windows can see the folder - can you access it and use it? I would say pull out the contents using windows, make a new folder / new copy of the contents and resave it.